# Review on DPA lavaliers 4061, 4060, and 4071

Tags: dpa, lavalier, production-audio, production-sound

People have been recommending DPA's to me for the longest time. I'm in the market to buy two at the moment and probably wireless. I wanted to know if anyone had experience with them and maybe recommend another company besides countryman that can compare to them. My main concern is capturing the best possible dialogue on set in all types of locations. I also will be running my boom with this set up.

Answer (score 2):

Within the standard limitations of lavs, they're awesome. I was pretty happy with my Countryman B3 lav, but the DPA 4060's never cease to impress. About the only thing sweeter is the Sanken COS-11, which seems to be the lav of choice when inter-cutting with Schoeps mics. But I'm a huge fan of the DPA modular connector system, especially as a sound designer who sometimes needs to just run them into a field recorder, instead of a bodypack (so nice to be able to do both).